# Run ".py", not typing 'python' in Ubuntu with Anaconda

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda

I'm using Ubuntu with the Anaconda environment to run Python scripts like this `python my_script.py`, but I want to type only `my_script.py`.

I've already tried adding these statements in the beginning of `my_script.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#/usr/lib/python3
#!/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/env python3
#!/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.7
```

It always returns

> my_script.py: command not found

.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2):

First do

```
chmod +x my_script.py
```

This will make the file executable.

Then you can run it as:

```
./my_script.py
```

Comment: It executes, but didn't interpreted python commands:

 ./my_script.py
./my_script.py: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `'test''
./my_script.py: line 1: `print('test')'

Comment: You need to show us the beginning of your script, the code after the lines you already posted